# ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: powershell

The code:

```
$Bios = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,Manufacturer,BIOSVersion | ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment -As List

$Bios2 = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -Property PSComputerName,Manufacturer,BIOSVersion | ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment -As Table

ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML -HTMLFragments $Bios,$Bios2 | Out-File AsExample.html
```

The error:

```
ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML -HTMLFragments $Bios,$Bios2 | Out-File AsExamp ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML
```

I don't understand why I am receiving the error. I've examined the help, and what I'm doing seems like it ought to be fair game:

```
-HTMLFragments <String[]>

    One or more HTML fragments, as produced by ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment.
    
    
        -HTMLFragments $part1,$part2,$part3

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    named
    Default value                
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

Comment: Afaik, `ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML` is not a standard PowerShell cmdlet, therefore I would check with the owner that build the function.

Comment: Are you sure ```$Bios``` and ```$Bios2``` are strings? You could try ```write-host $Bios.GetType().FullName; write-host $Bios2.GetType().FullName;``` to confirm...

Comment: Before $Bios is piped to ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment, and after it is piped to Select-Object, it is of type System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject. ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment accepts $Bios in its $InputObject parameter ByValue since it coerces it down to the regular old Object type, and then by the time $Bios runs through ConvertTo-EnhancedHTMLFragment, it gets spit out as an object of type System.String.

Comment: You should check it out. EnhancedHTML2 is a module created by OG Powershell Guru Don Jones, author of Powershell in a Month of Lunches, Powershell In-Depth, Powershell Scripting and Toolmaking in a Month of lunches, The Powershell Scripting and Toolmaking Book, and countless others. This example I am struggling with is character for character a working example from the Pluralsight course "Reporting with Windows Powershell HTML and EnhancedHTML." Don Jones is the head of curriculum at Pluralsight. It wouldn't be a gamble to assume this module is as stable as it gets. That's why it's so weird!

Comment: Also, note that the error returned is not a syntax error. Instead it says that it cannot resolve the parameter set. Indeed, there are 2 parameter sets for the ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML command but they both accept the -HTMLFragments parameter. Not only that, -HTMLFragaments is the only parameter that is at all required by either parameter set. Oh. Wait. THAT'S IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the error by specifying an additional parameter:

```
ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML -HTMLFragments $Bios,$Bios2 -CSSStyleSheet syles.css | Out-File AsExample.html
```

While reviewing the 2 available parameter sets for ConvertTo-EnhancedHTML, I noticed that there was only 1 parameter required in each one -- -HTMLFragments. The error was telling me it didn't know which parameter set I wanted to use. So what I ended up having to do was specify the -CSSStylesheet parameter, as that parameter and its opposing -CSSUri parameter are the only parameters unique to their respective sets. In other words, the command wouldn't execute because I had to specify one of the CSS parameters so powershell knew which parameter set to use DESPITE THE FACT THAT neither of the CSS parameters are actually required parameters. Wow!